# Show 3 to 5 products in a category with attribute value of sku in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created 10 products and two categories namsed 'A' and 'B' in my magento. These 10 products are assigned to category A not to B. I want to show only 3 products in category B on the basis of attribute value of sku.
I am using the below code in app/design/frontend/my_theme_package/mytheme/catalog/product/list.phtml:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sku', '9780007512119');    
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));    
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);   
$products->load();   
if ($products->getFirstItem()) 
{
    $product = $products->getFirstItem();
    echo $product->getName();
}
else 
{
    echo 'No product exists with the name ' . $name;
}
```

?>

Comment: I can't understand the question. Why just not assign these 3 product to category B, too?

Comment: I don't want to assign products in this category. what i simply want is that i have to fetch sku values from sales_flat_order_item and regarding to that sku i want to show those products

Answer (score 0):

The addAttributeToSelect method only filters attributes, not products based on attribute like addAttributeToFilter does.

Try this code instead:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', '9780007512119');    
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));    
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);   
$products->load();   
if ($products->getFirstItem()) 
{
    $product = $products->getFirstItem();
    echo $product->getName();
}
else 
{
    echo 'No product exists with the name ' . $name;
}
```